# Is there a point of marking a method in interface abstract?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I've refactored some methods to an interface and they were left with `abstract` modifier in the interface declaration. Something like this was in my code:

```
public interface TestAbstractMethod {

    public abstract void doSomething();

}
```

I noticed it accidentally now and I was actually surprised that the declaration wasn't marked as invalid, that it actually compiles and works.

Is `abstract` modifier allowed in an interface for a reason? Does this alter the interface's behavior in any way?

Comment: @Eran thanks for the duplicate, whatever I googled pointed me to sth like "differences between abstract class and interface"...

Comment: -1? Please only downvote if you think the *question* is bad. If it's a duplicate then find it and vote to close on that basis. The answer to this question is quite hard to find on Google.

Comment: @Bathsheba I didn't downvote, but it wasn't hard to find the duplicate. I Googled "jls interface abstact method" in order to find the relevant jls reference, and the 4th result was the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed, but its use is discouraged in the Java Language Specification, [§9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly abstract, so its body is always represented by a semicolon, not a block.
>
> It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public and/or abstract modifier for a method declared in an interface.